# ¿Como retornar un datatable a JSON?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tengo un metodo el cual va a un storedprocedure y genera un datatable , pero lo quiero retornar a un Json, alguien me podria apoyar, se los agradeceria mucho..

```
        public ActionResult ConsultaProvInt(int cClientes)
    {
        DataTable DTResult = null;
        if (cClientes > 0)
        {
            using (var db = new craEntities())
            {
                string strconection = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["craEntities2"].ConnectionString;

                string Query = "sp_ConsultaProvInt " + cClientes + ";";
                DTResult = GetDataTable(strconection, Query);
            }
        }

        string JSONString = string.Empty;
        JSONString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DTResult);
        return (JSONString);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes regresar el objeto con el nombre de la propiedad y su valor,
en este caso cada linea del datatable sera la representacion de un objeto
y el nombre de la propiedad es el nombre de la  columna

```
private string ObtenerJsonTabla(DataTable dt)
{
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
            List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
            Dictionary<string, object> row;
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                {
                    row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
                }
                rows.Add(row);
            }
            return serializer.Serialize(rows);
}


//haz una prueba y verifica el resultado
```

Comment: muchas gracias, si lo pude realizar sin problesma pero tengo una condicion, si se cumple solo manda los registros de un cliente y si no manda todos.
 entonces cuando manda todos, son al rededor de 25000 registros, cuando los envio a mi vista me manda el data como undefined y si mando pocos registros no hay problema los muestra correctamente. A que se debe eso?

Comment: Agrega un paginado, 25000 es demasiado que sean rangos de 1000 para la primer pagina 2000 para la segunda, ese parametro de paginado va para la consulta desde base de datos

Answer (score 0):

En principio, como lo tienes desarrollado está bien. Solo tienes que devover un objeto del tipo `JsonResult` con el resultado de deserializar el `DataTable`:

```
return Json(JSONString);
```